# Trouble identifying when user clicks inside circle with Zelle graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, zelle-graphics

I am creating a program in Python using Zelle graphics package. There is a moving circle that the user clicks on in order to make it return to the center of the screen. I cannot figure out how to identify when the user clicks inside of the circle. Here is the code I have written:

```
from graphics import *
from time import sleep
import random

Screen = GraphWin("BallFalling", 400 , 400);
Screen.setBackground('green')

ball = Circle(Point(200,200),25);
ball.draw(Screen);
ball.setFill('white')
ballRadius = ball.getRadius()
ballCenter = 0

directionX = (random.random()*40)-20;
directionY = (random.random()*40)-20;

clickx = Screen.getMouse().getX();
clicky = 0


while ball.getCenter().getX() + ball.getRadius() <= 400 and ball.getCenter().getY() + ball.getRadius() <= 400 and ball.getCenter().getX() >= 0 and ball.getCenter().getY() >= 0:
    ball.move(ball.getRadius()//directionX,ball.getRadius()//directionY)
    ballLocation = ball.getCenter().getX();
    ballLocationy = ball.getCenter().getY();
    sleep(1/15);
```

The main problem I am having is identifying the coordinates of the mouse click. I cannot find anything in the Zelle graphics package that says anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

The major issues I see are: you are calling `getMouse()` *before* the loop when you should be calling `checkMouse()` *inside* the loop; you have no code to compare the *distance* of the click from the ball; you have no code to return the ball to the center of the screen.

Below is my complete rework of your code addressing the above issues:

```
from time import sleep
from random import randrange
from graphics import *

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 400, 400
RADIUS = 25

def distance(graphic, point):
    x1, y1 = graphic.getCenter().getX(), graphic.getCenter().getY()
    x2, y2 = point.getX(), point.getY()

    return ((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2) ** 0.5

window = GraphWin("Ball Falling", WIDTH, HEIGHT)
window.setBackground('green')

ball = Circle(Point(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2), RADIUS)
ball.setFill('white')
ball.draw(window)

directionX = randrange(-4, 4)
directionY = randrange(-4, 4)

while True:
    center = ball.getCenter()
    x, y = center.getX(), center.getY()

    if not (RADIUS < x < WIDTH - RADIUS and RADIUS < y < HEIGHT - RADIUS):
        break

    point = window.checkMouse()

    if point and distance(ball, point) <= RADIUS:
        ball.move(WIDTH/2 - x, HEIGHT/2 - y)  # recenter
        directionX = randrange(-4, 4)
        directionY = randrange(-4, 4)
    else:
        ball.move(directionX, directionY)

    sleep(1/30)
```

There may still be subtle bugs and contants tweaking for you to sort out.